# Auto-registered dns record on windows server 2012

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012, windows-domain

I have two server with two network interfaces, one linked to LAN network and the second connected together for cluster heartbeat. The second interface is not accessible from other mahcine but the other server.
In this network there is a domain controller with dns management and every machine do a self registration with its dns record.
My trouble is that these servers register its name with both ip addresses, but one of these are not reachable in the net. Is there some option to give a priority to multiple address or deny the self registration for a particular network interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. In the Advanced TCP/IP Properties of the TCP/IPv4 properties of the NIC uncheck the box labeled "Register this connection's addresses in DNS".

---

[image]